# Can users with less reputation make one answer it as community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I am aware that users with 1 reputation can't edit the question, excluding the [Community](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community) user, but have a look at this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/644690/why-is-hibernation-still-used/644696#644696) including my answers all of the answers made by others were made as community answer by this [user](https://superuser.com/users/253847/user253847)

Is it possible for an user with less reputation(i.e without edit privilege) to make all answers as community wiki?

Comment: The question became CW because it exceeded the answer threshold

Comment: @Sathya http://superuser.com/help/privileges/community-wiki  30 answers are needed for it but right now only 15 answers

Comment: Threshold is [15 answers on Super User](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/133693)

Comment: I don't understand this question title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different sites can tweak the threshold for different parameters. For Super User [when more than 14 answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/133693) are posted, all posts on the question are converted into community wiki